# How to keep the standard arrow for HTML select element

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am styling a drop down in Firefox on Mac OS X, but it is changing the arrow from the standard look to an ugly down arrow.  What can I do to keep the standard form element with the nice up and down arrows, rather than the ugly down arrow?  I figure that my custom styles are causing it, but I want to be able to identify what causes the browser to switch it.

Here are the styles I'm using...

```
select {
    font: 400 16px/16px "Maven Pro";
    margin: 2px 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the CSS causing the difference.  It's actually a browser difference.  Form elements are something that you will have a very hard time standardizing across all browsers, except maybe submit buttons, which can be swapped out for images.

You can check around for some javascript plugins, but I wouldn't worry so much to get the safari select.  Folks using Firefox / IE are already used to seeing this type of select.

Comment: Indeed we are. Not to mention that "ugly" is, well, obviously extremely subjective. I have nothing against Macs (our office is entirely Mac-based) but to me, the up-down arrow is hideous, and I find the down-arrow beautifully simple. Anyway, generally it's not a good idea to override functionality that people are used to; form elements are one such item.